# How to do query with dynamic numbers of condition with SailsJS and MongoDB

Tags: model-view-controller, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm using SailsJS with MongoDB. 
For the Model "accounts" I'm using below code:

```
attributes: {   
    campaignID : { type: 'string' },
    cell : { type: 'string' },
    firstname : { type: 'string' },
    lastname : { type: 'string' },
    ssn : { type: 'integer' }
  }
```

And the problem is I don't how to write code to query the model in a way I can put any number of condition for the attributes in the model.
For example one query could be query all that with cell="5" And ssn="123456789"
Another query can be query all that with lastname="Borune".
Current I implemented below code in the controller:

```
list: function(req,res) {
        Accounts.find().where({
            campaignID' : {
                contains : req.param('campaignID')
            },
            cell:{
                contains : req.param('cell')
            }
        }).exec(function(err,data){
            if (err) res.json({error:'true'});
            res.json(data);
        });     
    }
```

But the problem is when I only want to use one attribute for the condition such as below address, no document will be returned since cell is not defined in the parameter.

```
http://localhost:1337/search?campaignID=testID2
```

How do I write the condition code so that I can specify any number of the condition as above and get the document that matches all the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just form your search criteria before you actually try to find anything. In case you're using query string to pass parameters (i.e. `/search?campaignID=foo&cell=42`) this should be something like:

```
list: function(req,res) {
  // req.query is {campaignID: 'foo', cell: '42'}
  var criteria = _.mapValues(req.query, function(val) {
    return {contains: val};
  })
  // criteria is {campaignID: {contains:'foo'}, cell: {contains: '42'}}
  Accounts.find(criteria).exec(function(err,data){
    if (err)  {
      return res.json({error:'true'});
    }
    res.json(data);
  });     
}
```

If you want to use request payload instead of query string you should change [req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) to [req.body](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body).

Don't forget `var _ = require('lodash')` on the top of controller file if you don't add it to sails autoload via config.